# Differential equation of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I have this simple differential equation: $y'=(\tan x)y.$

after integrating $\frac{y'}{y(x)}= \tan x$

i came up with $\log y(x)=-\log \cos(x)+1.$

now my question is this one:  why $ e^{-\log \cos(x)}=\sec(x)?$

thank you for your time

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thank you, i was wondering why latex wasn't working here, i'll fix right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that $\log(x)$ is for $\ln(x)$
$$e^{-\log \cos(x)}=(e^{\log \cos(x)})^{-1}=(\cos(x))^{-1}=\frac 1 {\cos(x)}=\sec(x)$$

Comment: thank you,i feel stupid now *facepalm* yes it is

Comment: yw No that's not a stupid question at all @GabrieleSortino